# MySQL: large amount of data

Tags: mysql, optimization, relational-database

first of all let me try to describe my problem.
Client is using application for a single year and he stored about 7 milions records into mysql database. His plan is to continue working even more on this application but it slows down with this amount of data.

Of course, the question is what will happend in next year, two or five...

This is pretty specific case where ~98% of data is stored in one single relational table (it is link between 2 tables).

What is the "best" solution in this case?
Best includes safe, well designed, the most logical solution which make the app usable for a long time and prevents this situation.

**My toughts:** keep current table as a history table and create a new one where I can store records for last 3 months and do some movements when records get old?

Respect!

Comment: That's what we do for some of our huge tables.

Comment: Also look at partitioned tables and the MERGE engine.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Just read through your question and I'm wondering how you define "best" in the question of "What is the best solution in this case?" Questions that generate opinion based answers are frowned upon here. Can you perhaps define what best means to you in a way (or ways) that is measurable?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar.
Louis, i agree with you so i edited it.

Comment: Before you do anything else, be certain you don't have indexing issues... 7 million rows is really not that large.

Answer (score 0):

For a many:many mapping table, use the tips described here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table . That will improve performance in many situations.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECTs` that are slowing down.

If that much of the data is in the 'link' table, how do the queries differ from a `CROSS JOIN`?

Partitioning rarely improves performance.  Again, need to see the queries.  `MERGE` is a MyISAM-based pre-PARTITION kludge.  Do not use it.

History table?  Do the queries look for the "latest" of something?  Again, need to see the schema and queries.